# Run VBScript using CFExecute throws error but works fine via command line

Tags: vbscript, coldfusion, wsh, cfexecute

I am trying to run a VBScript but CFExecute throws an error

```
<cfexecute name = "C:\Windows\System32\CScript.exe" 
            arguments = "//NoLogo D:\Excel.vbs D:\test.xls"
            variable = "data"
            timeout = "100">
 </cfexecute>
<cfdump var="#data#">
```

Error:

```
 Error: 424 Source: Microsoft VBScript runtime error Description: Object required
```

But when I run the VBScript with CMD it works fine

```
C:\Windows\System32 > cscript //nologo D:\Excel.vbs D:\test.xls
```

I have full admin access, so why am I getting this error?

Comment: *You* have full admin rights... but does the account that ColdFusion is running as have them?

Comment: @AdamCameron Yes they have.

Comment: Stick the full command & params in a batch file, and `<cfexecute>` that.

Comment: Checked with batch file:
@echo off
pushd %~dp0
cscript //nologo D:\Excel.vbs D:\sham.xls

Same error, let me check with Network Admin here.

Comment: Cool. I'd manually confirm that the account CF is running as has the appropriate effective permissions. Don't assume: *check*. Just to remove it as a factor.

Comment: Found Solution:

It was due to bug in the Windows 2008 server 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b81a3c4e-62db-488b-af06-44421818ef91/excel-2007-automation-on-top-of-a-windows-server-2008-x64?forum=innovateonoffice

For office automation (accessing via script and non-window based operation) we have to add Desktop folder inside
C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile

I added it and found success

Comment: could you please blog this?

Answer (score 7):

It was [due to bug in the Windows 2008 server](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b81a3c4e-62db-488b-af06-44421818ef91/excel-2007-automation-on-top-of-a-windows-server-2008-x64?forum=innovateonoffice). 
For office automation (accessing via script and non-window based operation) we have to add a "Desktop" folder inside

```
C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\system32
```

I added it and found success.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution. Just curious, did you have to create a "Desktop" subfolder in both locations? The thread made it sound like it depending on your o/s, ie `SysWOW64` for 64bit and `System32` for 32bit.

Comment: Yes @Leigh Desktop folder needs to be created at both directories.

Answer (score 0):

Create a vbscirpt file (.vbs). The code content would have the task you want to achieve.

The below example contains the vbscript file, that refreshes the excel and the cfm which executes the vbscript.

Sample vbscript file code:-

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set xl  = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xl.Visible = True

For Each f In fso.GetFolder("C:\inetpub\WebSites\Upload\").Files
  If LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(f.Name)) = "xlsx" Then
    Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(f.Path)
    wb.RefreshAll
    wb.Save
    wb.Close
  End If
Next

xl.Quit
```

Sample cfm file code:-

```
<cfexecute name = "C:\Windows\System32\cscript.exe" arguments = "C:\inetpub\WebSites\CSAT\test.vbs">
</cfexecute>
```

Comment: ok, but I have solved my current issue. Will add comment soon